# If I have a collection, how do I cycle through each object and return an array that each element is one attribute of each object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Say I have a collection `fruits` and each `fruit` object has an attribute called `color`. I would like to cycle through my entire `fruits` collection and have it be returned in 1 single array with the `color` of each parent being 1 element in the array.

So ideally, the output would look like this: `['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']`. It doesn't HAVE to be strings, it could be integers or anything that is an element in the array. The important thing is that each attribute for each object is contained in 1 cell of the array and I get only 1 array.

I tried something like this:

```
fruits.map { |fruit| return [fruit.color] }
```

But that returns multiple arrays - which is not what I want.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do:

```
fruits.map(&:color)
```

It's equivalent to:

```
fruits.map { |fruit| fruit.color }
```

and returns an array of values returned from block for each element in `fruits` array.

Your solution didn't work because instead of color, you returned array containing one element (which was color), so in the end you got an array of arrays in the form of:

```
[['green'], ['blue']] # etc.
```

Comment: Yep...that's exactly what was happening. Thanks very much for this. Btw...I never realized that a simple `fruit.color` would have done the trick. Muy interesante. I was overthinking it big time.